# Core Image Filter CISourceOverCompositing not working Properly

Tags: ios, iphone, photo, core-image

I am Working on Photo Editing App and I have to **merge two Images one Over another like this**.

[image]

I have implemented the **following code** to do so:
Here imgedit is the background image and
     imgEdit is the UIImageView containing imgedit.

```
        UIImage *tempImg = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"borderImg"]];
        CIImage *inputBackgroundImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:imgedit];
        CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:tempImg] ;

        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
        [filter setDefaults];
        [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
        [filter setValue:inputBackgroundImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

        CIImage *outputImage1 = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        imgEdit.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage1 fromRect:outputImage1.extent]];
```

But the **outputImage I am getting after implementing above code** is:
[image]

I have also tried to **resize** the input white frame image, by using following code:

```
        tempImg=[tempImg resizedImageToSize:CGSizeMake(imgEdit.image.size.width,imgEdit.image.size.height)];
```

By using above code image get resized properly but But that is also not working.

Please help me out from here.
Your valuable help will be highly appreciated.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Your background image is rectangle portrait and your mask image is square.. Actually what is the result you want to achieve from that image? or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like `CIContext` resizes itself for the bigger image size. Draw your background with the size of your mask image. for reference use this method `drawImage:inRect:fromRect:` method in `CIContext`. I am not much experienced with filters. Glad to know if you have questions too.

Comment: Actually I want to add the white frame that is shown above over the background image. The thing is when the background image is of square frame, then it is fine and I can get my desired output. but the problem comes when it is of rectangular shaped frame.
And many Thanks for your Quick Response.

Comment: so is that mean what your desired result is unknown to you itself?? Don't worry. I just have an idea. You just need to find the image is rectangle or square first with the size of the image. then draw your image in the context with the padding in top and bottom or left and right depending upon the image is wide or potrait respectively. so that the image will be shown inside the circle atleast.

Comment: Yes I had detected that image is square or rectangle. But how to manage the frame image to fit on background image, because I am having square frame image and how to convert that square image to get fit over the backgrount image.

Comment: Actually I want to set the frame image over the background image to get fit over it according to the frame of the background image. Also if you have any other idea about how to do so, than i can try that also.

Comment: Have you tried CGImage Scale? For example, UIImage *xyimdown= [UIImage imageNamed: [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:xydownnimage scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to resize is as follows:

```
inputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(inputBackgroundImage.extent.size.width/inputImage.extent.size.with, inputBackgroundImage.extent.size.height/inputImage.extent.size.height)];
```